# C# ApiController: I is possible to use it with typed parameter class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-apicontroller

In WebApi2, it is possible to use ApiController with a class like this?:

```
public class BillOfLadingsController<TDocument> : ApiController
    where TDocument : BillOfLadingModel, new()
{
    [HttpPost, Route("api/bill-of-ladings/create")]
    public async Task Create()
    {
        // Any code
    }
}
```

If so, anyone knows how to use it? without the typed parameter `<TDocument>` everything seem to work perfectly. With the typed parameter I get the 404 error.

Comment: The default controller selector has no mechanism to know what the type of TDocument is - how were you planning to supply it? Was it going to be a query string parameter, or part of the URL, or something? If you know how you were going to supply it, you can write your own controller selector that will implement this logic.

Comment: @RB.
The type of the TDocument is defined here: `where TDocument : BillOfLadingModel`

I found [this solution](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/) but still unable to implement it.